# Azure Webjob to run whilst listening to events?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub

I will have an Azure webjob which will run every x minutes.
The job listens to EventHub (pub/sub) for any incoming messages and processes the message.

What is the best way to create/design the webjob so that it stays awake processing the messages? I am unsure if always on is the right way to do this or just run the webjob every few minutes however during the executing of the webjob, I want the code to run so it can wait and listen for messages rather than just exiting almost immediately (imagine program.cs without a console.readline!)

Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: Did you read this https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support? Also, using a continuous running webjob combined with an `EventProcessorHost` is an option, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953543/using-an-azure-webjob-to-read-from-an-eventhub

Comment: _"...What is the best way..."_ is sadly subject to opinion and so off-topic for SO. [ask]

Comment: As you said, you would pick up the option provided by Mikhail to implement your scenario. Since Mikhail's effort could help you, kindly mark it as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 main options:

1. Create a console app and use [Event Processor Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host). Deploy it as a continuous web job.
2. Create a console app and use [WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support) to create an EventHub-triggered function. Deploy it as a continuous web job.
3. Create an Azure Function with [Event Hub trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs).

In 1 and 2 you will pay per hour of your Web App Plan instance. There's no point in making job timer-based instead of continuous: you keep paying per hour unless you shut down the Web App instance.

In 3 you pay per function execution time, which might be much cheaper if the amount of events is low.

Comment: Thanks. Being new to Azure I am trying to understand how the app will run without exiting immediately but seems I need to maybe go for option 2 here since then it would trigger my web job and process the message from the queue.